# How do I add column from an original dataframe to scraped data?

Tags: r, rvest

I have two columns "name" and "link" which indicates the name of the firm and the link to scrape from. How do I put back the name column so that each row of scraped data will have a column with the corresponding name of the firm?

```
List.Of.Tabs <- map(pages, ~ {
  name <- .x[1]
  link <- .x[2]
  webpage <- read_html(link)
  tbls <- html_nodes(webpage, "table")
  tbls_ls <- html_table(tbls,fill = TRUE)
  pos1 <- possibly(function(tbls) bind_rows(tbls) %>% 
                   filter_all(any_vars(. %in% c("Ireland", "Japan")))
                   , otherwise = NA)
  pos1(tbls_ls)
```

Results should be something like that:

```
results <- data.frame(subsidiaries = c('Microsoft Japan','Microsoft Ireland'), 
                      country = c('Japan', 'Ireland'),
                      name = c('Microsoft','Microsoft'))
```

Comment: What is your input data? What packages are you using?

Answer (score 1):

Based on the code, we may need to `mutate` (i.e. creating a column of 'name' from the already created 'name' in the first line of code)

```
List.Of.Tabs <- map(pages, ~ {
  name <- .x[1]
  link <- .x[2]
  webpage <- read_html(link)
  tbls <- html_nodes(webpage, "table")
  tbls_ls <- html_table(tbls,fill = TRUE)
  pos1 <- possibly(function(tbls) bind_rows(tbls) %>% 
                   filter_all(any_vars(. %in% c("Ireland", "Japan"))) %>%
                   mutate(name = name) # changed here
                   , otherwise = NA)
  pos1(tbls_ls)

  })
```